# The Colossal Gosper curve

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

## Task

Produce this 24kB ASCII art output:

```
                                                                          ________
                                                                          \       \
                                                                ________   \____   \                                                                ________
                                                                \       \      /   /                                                                \       \
                                                                 \____   \____/   /   ____                                                ________   \____   \
                                                                     /            \   \   \                                               \       \      /   /
                                                                ____/   ________   \   \   \        ________                               \____   \____/   /   ____
                                                               /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \                                  /            \   \   \
                                                              /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \                            ____/   ________   \   \   \        ________
                                                              \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /                           /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \
                                                    ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____                    /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \
                                                    \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \                   \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /
                                          ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \        ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____
                                          \       \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \
                                           \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \
                                               /            \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /
                                          ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/
                                         /        \       \   \  /            \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /   /
                                        /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____
                                        \   \   \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /
                                         \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /
                                          \  /            \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /
                                           \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/
                                                \       \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \   \  /
                                                 \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________
                                                     /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \
                                                ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \
                                               /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /
                                              /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____
                                              \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /
                                               \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /
                                                   /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /
                                              ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/
                                             /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /
                                            /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____
                                            \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /
                                  ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /
                                  \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /
                        ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/
                        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /            \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /
                         \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________
                             /            \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \
                        ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \
                       /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /
                      /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____
                      \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \
            ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \        ________
            \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \
  ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \
  \       \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /
   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____
       /            \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /
  ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /
 /        \       \   \  /            \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \  /   /       /
/   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/
\   \   \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /            \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /   /
 \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____
  \  /            \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /
   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /
        \       \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /
         \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/
             /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /       /
        ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________
       /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \
      /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \
      \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /
       \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____
           /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /
      ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /
     /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \  /   /       /
    /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/
    \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \      /   /
     \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____
      \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \   \  /            \  /   /
       \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /
            \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /            \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \      /
             \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/
              \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /            \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /
               \/              \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/
                                \  /            \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /
                                 \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/
                                      \       \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /
                                       \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____
                                           /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /
                                      ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /
                                     /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /
                                    /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/
                                    \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /
                                     \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/
                                         /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /
                                    ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/
                                   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /
                                  /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____
                                  \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /            \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /
                                   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /
                                    \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \      /
                                     \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/
                                          \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /            \   \   \   \  /
                                           \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   ________
                                               /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \   \  /   /        \       \
                                          ____/   ________   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \
                                         /        \       \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /
                                        /   ____   \____   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____
                                        \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \  /   /
                                         \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \/   /
                                             /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \   \   \      /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \  /   /       /
                                        ____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/
                                       /        \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \   \  /            \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \      /   /
                                      /   ____   \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/   ________   \   \   \____/   /   ____
                                      \   \   \   \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \       \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /            \       \   \  /            \  /   /
                                       \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/   ________   \____   \   \/   ________   \/   /
                                        \  /   /        \  /   /       /   /        \   \   \      /            \   \   \   \  /   /        \       \      /   /        \       \      /
                                         \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   /   ____   \   \   \____/              \   \   \   \/   /   ____   \____   \____/   /   ____   \____   \____/
                                              \   \   \      /   /        \   \   \   \  /                        \  /   /        \  /   /       /            \   \   \      /
                                               \   \   \____/   /   ____   \   \   \   \/                          \/   /   ____   \/   /   ____/   ________   \   \   \____/
                                                \  /            \   \   \   \  /   /                                    \   \   \      /   /        \       \   \  /
                                                 \/              \   \   \   \/   /   ____                               \   \   \____/   /   ____   \____   \   \/
                                                                  \  /   /        \  /   /                                \  /            \   \   \      /   /
                                                                   \/   /   ____   \/   /                                  \/              \   \   \____/   /   ____
                                                                        \   \   \      /                                                    \  /            \  /   /
                                                                         \   \   \____/                                                      \/   ________   \/   /
                                                                          \  /                                                                    \       \      /
                                                                           \/                                                                      \____   \____/
                                                                                                                                                       /
                                                                                                                                                  ____/
```

(It’s a fourth-generation [Gosper curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper_curve).)

## Rules

- You may optionally add any amount of **trailing** spaces to each line.
- You may optionally add an **equal** amount of **leading** spaces to all lines.
- You may prepend or append any amount of lines consisting of zero or more spaces.
- You may submit a function or a full program.
- The shortest code in **bytes** wins.